# Why is Hardy motivating integrals be defining a new function $\phi'(x)=\psi(x)$?

Tags: calculus, real-analysis

**Reference:** G.H. Hardy - A Course of Pure Mathematics (ed. 3) page 229-230

I am working on the above book and am on the section where he introduces integrals. The way he begins to introduce them is to suppose there is a function $\psi(x)$. Then we wish to determine a function such that $\phi'(x)=\psi(x)$

He then provides his definition of the integral:

> **Definition:** If $\psi(x)$ is the derivative of $\phi(x)$, then we call $\phi(x)$ an integral, or integral function of $\psi(x)$. The operation of forming $\psi(x)$ from $\phi(x)$ we call integration.

What I don't understand is why to go to the trouble of introducing $\psi(x)$. Instead of writing:

$\int\psi(x)dx$

it would be just as valid to write:

$\int\phi'(x)dx$

Without having to make the step of introducing $\psi(x)$.

**Question:** Why does Hardy introduce another new function instead of just using the derivative function?

Comment: Because $\psi$ represents the function one is starting with; Hardy is saying: *given* some function $\psi$, then an "integral function of $\psi$" is *defined to be* any function $\phi$ such that $\phi^\prime = \psi$.

Comment: @kjo your comment has cleared up my confusion. Could you rewrite your comment as an answer so that I may accept ti?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Hardy is saying that *given* some function $\psi$, then *define* an "integral function of $\psi$" to be *any* function $\phi$ such that $\phi^\prime = \psi$.

Comment: Usually also called an "*indefinite* integral", or as I prefer, a "*primitive*".

Comment: And also "antiderivative", I know.  I was just paraphrasing Hardy, as quoted by the OP.